# is there a better way to write a nested conditional in jq?

Tags: jq

I tried to use the `if X and Y then A else B` in jq, but there is some hidden context going on which gives errors. It is as if the condition in X changes a context or state that Y and A then use, but if I nest the if statements I do not get that behavior.

This works:

```
if .foo == "bar" then 
  if  [.bazes[] | .bat=="blah"] | any then .add = "added" else . end 
else . end
```

This does not work:

```
if .foo == "bar" and [.bazes[] | .bat=="blah"] | any then 
   .add = "added"
else . end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that fails does so because the associativity is not what you want.  Adding parentheses to make your intentions clear is usually not a bad idea anyway:

```
if .foo == "bar" 
   and ([.bazes[] | .bat=="blah"] | any)
then .add = "added"
else . end
```

#### any/2

You could circumvent the issue, achieve a more efficient solution, and conform more closely to English usage by using `any/2`:

```
if .foo == "bar" 
   and any(.bazes[]; .bat=="blah")
then .add = "added"
else . end
```